# Particular case of Beal's Conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

Is it known that there exist no coprime positive integers $A$, $B$ and $C$ such that $A^3+B^4=C^3$?  This is a particular case of [Beal's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal%27s_conjecture).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an unspecific question around a well-known open problem.

Comment: Well, I disagree. Why is the question *unspecific*? The OP is asking if a particular case of the conjecture has been settled, and actually it has.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi as it seems you want to disagree with me it would have seemed like common courtesy to notify me of this fact.

Comment: @quid: I'm sorry, I just forgot to use the "@", I surely did not mean to be impolite.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Okay, no problem. *Unspecific* was meant as not very well-motivated or researched or "just asking around" (not as unclear). To wit, the information you give is basically on the site linked to. Thus, it does not seem like a research level question.

Comment: @quid  Where is it "on the site linked to"?  I don't think the Wikipedia page has any conclusion for this case, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: It lists the case $(3,3,n)$ for $n$ including $4$, which is for integral solutions (which is  what is considered there) clearly the same as your case.

Comment: @quid  The order is important.  This case is different:(3,4,3) or equivalently (4,3,3).

Comment: No it is not different, as the answer below spells out. This very result is mentioned there (it quotes another article but that article mentions the result in the answer for this case).

Comment: @quid: Wikipedia states the conjecture only for *positive* integers, and in this case $(3,3,4)$ is not the same as $(3,4,3)$. It is true that, with a little supplementary effort, Bruin's paper with the solution for *arbitrary* integers is no difficult to find on the web.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi yes, I know, which is why I stressed here "for integral solutions (which is what is considered there)" [in the paper mentioned for that case]. Anyway if you think *this* makes this a research question. Fine. // Added: the effort you mention would be **to follow the link given on Wikipedia for this very case,** to a paper by Beukers where very clearly the solutions can be integers.

Comment: @quid: of course, I do *not* think that this makes this a research question :-) I just think that this can be a raisonable question for those that are non-experts in the field, even if the answer is admittedly not too difficult to find on the web. 
I agree that this is somehow a borderline case, but it also seems to me that there is a certain consensus that MO should not exclude questions posed by mathematicians outside their comfort area (and that sometimes can be trivial for the specialists).

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi in general yes, *yet not* if these question concern famous open problems.

Comment: @quid: I agree with you that general questions on famous open problems should be closed. Nonetheless, it is my opinion that *precise questions* on *particular cases* of famous problems can be accepted. But I guess that this is open to debate.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi yes. the key  point though is *if* one considers this question as precise or unspecific (to go back to the start). In a literal sense it likely is precise, but in reality it seems like a pretty random/unspecific question to me. But this discrepancy in our opinions was already established at the start, :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can rewrite the diophantine equation in the form $C^3-A^3 = B^4,$ that is $C^3+ (-A)^3=B^4.$

Now, Bruin proved that integer solutions to $x^3+y^3 = z^n$ with $n \in \{4, \, 5\}$ and $xyz \neq 0$ satisfy $\textrm{gcd}(x, \, y, \, z) >1$, see

N. Bruin, [On powers as sums of two cubes](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F10722028_9), Lecture Notes in Computer Science Volume **1838** (2000), pp 169-184.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I could now ask the question for exponents (3,4,5), which seems to be the new leading unproven candidate, but don't want to give @quid an ulcer!

Comment: @bobuhito don't worry about me. Please go ahead. I will just ignore it.

Comment: @bobuhito: quid is right saying that the cases in wich Bael's Conjecture has been proven are easily find with a Google search. For instance, Beuker's paper cited in the Wikipedia's article and the references given therein are a good starting point. If you do not find anything about a specific set of exponents, it is likely that that case is currently unsettled.

Comment: (3,4,5) was settled by Samir Siksek and myself: "Partial descent on hyperelliptic curves and the generalized Fermat equation $x^3 + y^4 + z^5 = 0$",
Bull. London Math. Soc. 44, 151-166 (2012). It's also on arXiv: http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.1979 .